# Why do dogs roll around in random patches of grass

Tags: dogs, behavior

When I bring my dog into the dog park, It's not uncommon to see a dog rolling around in the grass, but sometimes, there will be a particular spot int he grass that nearly all the dogs nearby will want to roll in.

I've even seen dogs compete over rolling around in the spot.

Why do all the dogs want to roll in this spot?

Comment: Perhaps leaving their scent? [Dognip? ;)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOavCNOKJww)

Comment: Is your answer here http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/471/why-does-my-dog-roll-in-gross-stuff ?

Comment: related, but not duplicate http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/542/should-i-let-my-dog-roll-in-the-grass

Comment: I think there are certain grasses or fungi that smell funky and makes dogs want the scent on them ... and that comes from the traits of their wolf ancestors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reitierating from my post here [Should I let my dog roll in the grass?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/542/should-i-let-my-dog-roll-in-the-grass/552#552)

Dogs enjoy rolling in grass for many reasons.

- to remove unwanted odors (usually human inflicted like shampoo)
- to scratch, for pleasure
- to take some of the scent from the grass

Dog's love to disguise their scent with the environment, it's olfactory camouflage to hide from predators and remain undetected by prey.

Comment: Olfactory camouflage! :)